# Transparent gradient not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

Chrome/Firefox (latest builds):

[image]

Safari (latest build):

[image]

The code:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,128,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,128,0,.6) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

Tried:

```
rgba(255,255,255,0.001)
transparent
-webkit-linear-gradient
```

Comment: Do you have a `base-tag` in your `head-section` by any change? Had some trouble with gradients in the past. Removing this tag fixed it for me.

Comment: @PeterBode no .

Comment: Safari has a known issue (see: https://css-tricks.com/thing-know-gradients-transparent-black/ ) of rendering `transparent` as `transparent black`. Have you tried changing `transparent` to something else like `rgba(255,255,255,0)`

Comment: @Robert it renders to "transparent color". So in the example above it's a "transparent white" but I can change it to "transparent red" for example. But it should be only "transparent". I always use `rgba`, never keywords.

Comment: Well @Robert, I can do the trick using the previous color. In this case: `rgba(255,128,0,0)`. But it's not purely transparent.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error is if Safari doesn't have a background declaration for the parent element. So for example if `html` has no background but `body` does you get the `transparent black` bug regardless of whether you're using keyword or RGBA. Setting a background to the parent element seems to resolve the issue. Can you confirm if you're encountering a similar result?

Comment: @Robert I always set the background in `html`. And yup, I've set the background also in body and now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is known and best explained in the link below:

https://css-tricks.com/thing-know-gradients-transparent-black/

Below are few related links on github for the same issue:

https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/315

https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/2010

Eventually I believe that you need a work around to do so until they come up with a fix in future releases.

Best Wishes